# How to print a form value using jquery in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Suppose I have a form with some input values(name, mobile_number, age and gender).

After fill up the form while I clicked submit button, I want to print the form values.

I have already tried with jQuery but not get the exact result.

**Here is my result**

[image]

But I want to print the form data like this

```
Name : Raff
Mobile Number : 016******* 
Age : ** 
Gender : Male
```

**Here is my form**

```
<form action="{{url('/add-prescription')}}" method="post" id="new_prescription_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-8">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="body">
                                <div class="row clearfix">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-line">
                                                 <b>Name: </b>
                                                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="name" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-line">
                                                 <b>Mobile Number: </b>
                                                <input type="text" id="mobile_number" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="mobile_number" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row clearfix">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-line">
                                                 <b>Age: </b>
                                                <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="age" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class= "col-sm-6">
                                         <b>Gender: </b>
                                        <select id="gender" class="form-control show-tick" name="gender" required>
                                            <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
                                            <option value="1">Male</option>
                                            <option value="2">Female</option>
                                            <option value="3">Others</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect" value="print" onclick="PrintElem()">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div> 
                </div>

            </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
function PrintElem()
    {
        var divToPrint=document.getElementById('new_prescription_form');

        var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

        newWin.document.open();

        newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

        newWin.document.close();

        setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10); 
    }
```

How to solve this ? Anybody help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the values of input fields and add those into the print HTML, this can be achieved using JavaScript , you don't need JQuery for this.

Update your PrintElem function with this and check

```
function PrintElem()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var mobile_number =  document.getElementById('mobile_number').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    var divToPrint=document.getElementById('new_prescription_form');

    var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

    newWin.document.open();

    newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()"><div><p><lable>Name :</lable><span>'+name+'</span></p><p><lable>Mobile Number :</lable><span>'+mobile_number+'</span></p><p><lable>Age:</lable><span>'+age+'</span></p><p><lable>Gender</lable><span>'+gender+'</span></p></div></body></html>');

    newWin.document.close();

    setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10); 
}
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery example</title>
<link
 href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"
    type="text/javascript">
 </script>

<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#InputText').keyup(function() {
             $('#OutputText').val($(this).val());
             $('#DIVTag').html('<b>' + $(this).val() + '</b>');
            });
        });     
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="JQDiv">
        <form id="JQForm" action="">
            <p>
                <label for="InputText">
                Enter Name : 
                </label><br /> 
                <input id="InputText" type="text" name="inputBox" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="OutputText">
                Output in box
                </label><br/> 

                <input id="OutputText" type="text" name="outputBox" readonly="readonly" />
            </p>
            <p>
                Output in div
            </p> 
                <div id="DIVTag"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

> Similarly you can do it for other form fields.
>   Also use angularjs to achieve same functionalities you can

This is what you are looking for?
Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But this is not my targeted answer. I want to print the form value